# Exclude directories in ZSH glob

Tags: zsh, globbing

With zsh, you can use `**/*` as a short alternative to using `find`. Is there any way to restrict that to regular files, that is an equivalent to the `-type f` option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can append `(.)` to a pattern to restrict matches to plain files as long as the `Bare_Glob_Qual` option is set, which it is by default unless you have zsh emulating some other shell.  This is covered in the [Glob Qualifiers section of the zshexpn manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

So the full pattern to match regular files in the current directory and any of its subdirectories would be `**/*(.)`.

Comment: While your answer perfectly answers the question body -- I want to comment on @Erik's question title: To exclude directories use `**/*(^/)` -- with that symbolic links, fifos etc are listed, whereas with `**/*(.)` they are not.